# Your connection is not private - Attackers might be trying to steal your information

Tags: wireless-networking, google-chrome, email, security, malware

I would like to know what does this error message means in the chrome and when I try to access in my case hotmail and I get this below message and if I try to access gmail or yahoo or facebook I do not get this message, can anybody help me educate?

Just you know I have malware bytes premium and also McAfee on my system and I'm using windows 10

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from hotmail.com
>   (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).
>   NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
>
> hotmail.com normally uses encryption to protect your information. When
>   Google Chrome tried to connect to hotmail.com this time, the website
>   sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. This may happen when an
>   attacker is trying to pretend to be hotmail.com, or a Wi-Fi sign-in
>   screen has interrupted the connection. Your information is still
>   secure because Google Chrome stopped the connection before any data
>   was exchanged.

You cannot visit hotmail.com right now because the website uses HSTS. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page will probably work later.
when I double click on NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID then I see the following

```
Subject: *.mail.live.com
Issuer: Microsoft IT SSL SHA2
Expires on: Feb 17, 2018
Current date: May 2, 2017
PEM encoded chain:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIH/TCCBeWgAwIBAgITWgAH0HeSax/6XsZlkgAAAAfQdzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF
................................
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: I believe it's a problem on MS server side as I also get the same issue. However www.hotmail.com(instead of hotmail.com) works correctly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have encountered this issues several times before. In most cases, it's caused by:

- Wrong date & time on your computer (or device you are using).
- Google Chrome cookies & cached files.
- DNS cached.
- Antivirus blocks SSL connections.

The first step you should do is to check and verify again the date & time to make sure it's correct.

Next, check the scope of this issue. To do so, use another web browser like Opera or Firefox and visit the same HTTPS website. If you get the same (or similar) error, then it's not a fault on your Google Chrome browser.

In this case, I would recommend clearing DNS cached by using the following command in Command Prompt:

```
 ipconfig /flushdns
```

In case this error only occurs on your Chrome browser, then try to clean up all cookies and cached files on your browser and try again.

Besides, if you are using antivirus application or firewall that has the SSL scanning feature (or web shield), it could cause this error as well. You can test by turning off those programs temporarily.

Source: [Fix Your Connection Is Not Private Error In Google Chrome](https://bytebitebit.com/687/your-connection-is-not-private/)

Answer (score 2):

**Update: MS fixes the issue with a new certificate which properly includes `hotmail.com` domain.** so no more error message when accessing `hotmail.com` on Chrome.

Below is for reference only.

---

I believe it's not a "sth. is wrong with your configuration" situation instead it's a server side issue. I'd like to write a long answer so anyone facing the same issue(Chrome 58 and hotmail.com) wouldn't waste time in "securing" the system.

As of today(May 8th 2017)
hotmail.com has following certificate

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIIH/TCCBeWgAwIBAgITWgAH0HeSax/6XsZlkgAAAAfQdzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF
>   ADCBizELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCldhc2hpbmd0b24xEDAOBgNVBAcT
>   B1JlZG1vbmQxHjAcBgNVBAoTFU1pY3Jvc29mdCBDb3Jwb3JhdGlvbjEVMBMGA1UE
>   CxMMTWljcm9zb2Z0IElUMR4wHAYDVQQDExVNaWNyb3NvZnQgSVQgU1NMIFNIQTIw
>   HhcNMTcwNDE3MTc0MjIzWhcNMTgwMjE3MTc0MjIzWjAaMRgwFgYDVQQDDA8qLm1h
>   aWwubGl2ZS5jb20wggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDf1hD1
>   tIfgW3k8stvmQJCZEpXhcYOmH597ePSSvnozmNTUUp++65+k1uvmFGrbKtaSvuRu
>   FpiJvFvJ6KJnNFNgKmyzpgUKC1tud4pC7pIMO4uRfxTGPVS7AUZiAZCu1xzPOaDR
>   z9/9I94Emhth+gr1mSOcDlOf2PZnCNoRVfmMiwtcn7RUzzzklHZAlGCirwe/HOk4
>   An5F0dCOv4eoOaquvpVv15d3tdy+Tep7iRDg0LvJ5EWhpBhvBymipSVfMK9aSQhC
>   kvyXEdKHWmZzcAOGuA68TGNCYAVbSfVRJzrrhgGqb8GkydSuFKF8NROA7NQyzeTT
>   n89hxd3CUxGvuM6JAgMBAAGjggPIMIIDxDAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUv8Vqe/TPUXEp1tkE
>   KXc0cvw9JTQwCwYDVR0PBAQDAgSwMB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFFGvJCac9GgiV4AmKztG
>   YhV7HsylMH0GA1UdHwR2MHQwcqBwoG6GNmh0dHA6Ly9tc2NybC5taWNyb3NvZnQu
>   Y29tL3BraS9tc2NvcnAvY3JsL21zaXR3d3cyLmNybIY0aHR0cDovL2NybC5taWNy
>   b3NvZnQuY29tL3BraS9tc2NvcnAvY3JsL21zaXR3d3cyLmNybDBwBggrBgEFBQcB
>   AQRkMGIwPAYIKwYBBQUHMAKGMGh0dHA6Ly93d3cubWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbS9wa2kv
>   bXNjb3JwL21zaXR3d3cyLmNydDAiBggrBgEFBQcwAYYWaHR0cDovL29jc3AubXNv
>   Y3NwLmNvbTA9BgkrBgEEAYI3FQcEMDAuBiYrBgEEAYI3FQiDz4lNrfIChaGfDIL6
>   yn2B4ft0gU+HtM98gc26MgIBZAIBHDAdBgNVHSUEFjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAQYIKwYB
>   BQUHAwIwTgYDVR0gBEcwRTBDBgkrBgEEAYI3KgEwNjA0BggrBgEFBQcCARYoaHR0
>   cDovL3d3dy5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL3BraS9tc2NvcnAvY3BzADAnBgkrBgEEAYI3
>   FQoEGjAYMAoGCCsGAQUFBwMBMAoGCCsGAQUFBwMCMIIBqwYDVR0RBIIBojCCAZ6C
>   DyoubWFpbC5saXZlLmNvbYIKKi5saXZlLmNvbYINKi5ob3RtYWlsLmNvbYIJKi5t
>   c24uY29tgggqLmFmeC5tc4INbWFpbC5saXZlLmNvbYINaG90bWFpbC5jby5qcIIN
>   aG90bWFpbC5jby51a4IQaG90bWFpbC5saXZlLmNvbYIPaG90bWFpbC5tc24uY29t
>   gg93d3cuaG90bWFpbC5jb22CE3d3dy5ob3RtYWlsLm1zbi5jb22CDHd3dy5saXZl
>   LmNvbYIRd3d3Lm1haWwubGl2ZS5jb22CD20ubWFpbC5saXZlLmNvbYIRY29udGFj
>   dHMubGl2ZS5jb22CD3Blb3BsZS5saXZlLmNvbYINaG9tZS5saXZlLmNvbYIYY29s
>   NDMwLXNlYy5tYWlsLmxpdmUuY29tghtvcmlnaW4uYmx1MTgwLm1haWwubGl2ZS5j
>   b22CG29yaWdpbi5kdWIxMzEubWFpbC5saXZlLmNvbYIfb3JpZ2luLmNvbDQzMC1z
>   ZWMubWFpbC5saXZlLmNvbYILbXNzbC5hZngubXMwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggIB
>   AJIg/Pcc3FtEe4bazzwRXl5Dirjz69TlBrkHBhA/Mf9fw2nEAGXl9xckjL48yG3a
>   yPWUolT4sAO8aWkqAtTKjpB7Qtiuk/M8ZLI5LENeKlb8d4RRbKs/qQhqK07/5PaI
>   XptcqSu6mGY6UcdKsdzlpEjMhrfhDPStReZQPs9pkeD13IkxgPONih2IyoMdsqEz
>   JUHIBgs4Yz0v7OHZeE2GZ8wkCGukbUC+HyNTpWX1v8/1RSzbp7Bpe2kv5Y3BWBiK
>   HlYvCvwYfr2660wr1tllQc/6JqPecWAmENlbzEoArH5P0JPmCRlTFgHnkQw8jU/4
>   6JLpt37XOpdQRPe6d4KG1qoAI1hdGjLdC2sRwVTKUS0LWF/U0QpeJzGa9L1rUBmh
>   DdwzvSd914MMgSV66QfA4hswfhXtV1k8Rf7Tyngr965n2QO3uLSpUrZ9wENSSPu2
>   0RDIQRssQAVgX3o5dAhf2HUGHzRbqTZDA7x01HKYBcAxpdmQP8JAS48bY6x1CeHh
>   F10tXhJVtnmSdjrEdMTB0uf6EUSYXQE40HckguyggQwK61gq74KszoP96l8rTGJe
>   7OQunGtgykbPzW81ecE2PcIJ5mN7h0rfvat5xAVj+WxJ3BTUoCFxYIw3Xal+z6Hn
>   Js9aVZBWUcn6TGVDApG5QghlXyUg8ilE1NgHdGpmpJyQ
>   -----END CERTIFICATE-----

Which can be decoded [here](https://www.sslchecker.com/certdecoder)(or just search "ssl certificate decoder") it has common name `*.mail.live.com` and SAN:

> *.mail.live.com, *.live.com, *.hotmail.com, *.msn.com, *.afx.ms, mail.live.com, hotmail.co.jp, hotmail.co.uk, hotmail.live.com,
>   hotmail.msn.com, www.hotmail.com, www.hotmail.msn.com, www.live.com,
>   www.mail.live.com, m.mail.live.com, contacts.live.com,
>   people.live.com, home.live.com, col430-sec.mail.live.com,
>   origin.blu180.mail.live.com, origin.dub131.mail.live.com,
>   origin.col430-sec.mail.live.com, mssl.afx.ms

Note that it has `*.hotmail.com` as well as `www.hotmail.com` but no `hotmail.com`, and [*.hotmail.com does **NOT** cover hotmail.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/310530/should-a-wildcard-ssl-certificate-secure-both-the-root-domain-as-well-as-the-sub).

So most likely there is some change in Chrome 58 which properly implements this check and blocks `hotmail.com`. Using `www.hotmail.com` instead of `hotmail.com` should eliminate the error.

And the same error is caught with Firefox but since `hotmail.com` is a 301 redirect Firefox just let it pass but there is actually something wrong.[image: Firefox]

---

On May 9th, 2017 `hotmail.com` has a new certificate with `hotmail.com` included so no more error message on Chrome.

> Subject Alternative Names: *.mail.live.com, *.live.com, *.hotmail.com,
>   *.msn.com, *.afx.ms, mail.live.com, hotmail.co.jp, hotmail.co.uk, hotmail.live.com, hotmail.msn.com, www.hotmail.com,
>   www.hotmail.msn.com, www.live.com, www.mail.live.com, m.mail.live.com,
>   contacts.live.com, people.live.com, home.live.com,
>   col430-sec.mail.live.com, origin.blu180.mail.live.com,
>   origin.dub131.mail.live.com, origin.col430-sec.mail.live.com,
>   mssl.afx.ms, hotmail.com, live.com

Comment: I'm getting the same error on/off and the way I fix for now is just clear the browser cache and it works for me.

Comment: It's not about cache as I did my test with inprivate mode and got same error yesterday. It's working now because MS just updated their certificate and has `hotmail.com` included. The new certificate was issued on 5/5/2017.

Comment: interesting ... but from last few days I have been using my Hotmail account by clearing the cache, thanks for the detail post. 1+

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you cannot establish a secure connection, and the HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security) used by Hotmail will not allow the security of the connection to be "negotiated down" to an unacceptably risky level.
   It could be that the date/time on your PC is not correct, which would cause the systems to disagree about the "freshness" of the security details.  Use a cellphone or something that has known good time and update your PC's time and date.
   I am discounting the "Wi-Fi sign-in screen" suggestion in the error message because you are able to access other sites.
   For more on HSTS, I recommend the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), and as a next step in troubleshooting, ensure your calendar and clock are set right.  Good luck!

Comment: my desktop computer date/time is correct and if i use my cellphone i have no problem and i can check my email only happening with my desktop, i reboot my router and wifi too but still same. any other thing?